# How to run an application without internet

Tags: javascript, html, css, offlineapps

I have an application build on HTML-css-javascript.
It is used to sale-purchase goods.
It is running online and also has app as well to run on tab/mobile.
Now, I want to run the application on machine without internet and without configuring in IIS.

Is there any possible way to do that??

Comment: You can use kiosk mode or run an HTA on a windows box with IE

Comment: If is only html-css-js, you don't need any server. A local copy of app(folder) is ok. But if you have an MySql/SQLite/... any db with data of goods/order, you have to setup the enviroment accordingly. A lot of XAMP/LAMP are available for allmost any OS

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to download the application at least once to make use of the HTML5 offline application feature. So there is no possibility to do what you want. If you're interested in offline application mode, here is a very good [article](http://diveintohtml5.info/offline.html) about it.

In case you want to run your application locally use [MAMP](https://www.mamp.info). MAMP installs a local server environment. There are also other tools like MAMP, if you don't like it.

Good luck!

Comment: Yes I want it to run locally, the application is using database build on MS Sql Server

Comment: you'll need to migrate your MSSQL DB to MySQL. But I think there is a wizzard in phpmyadmin which can do this.